# Inequalities for Inner products.

Tags: inequality

Are there special versions of Inequalities for inner products?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start with the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$
-2 \langle \alpha(x-y),\beta(v-w)\rangle \le 2 |\langle \alpha(x-y),\beta(v-w)\rangle| \\
\le 2 \Vert \alpha(x-y) \Vert \cdot \Vert \beta(v-w) \Vert \\
= 2 \bigl( \frac{1}{\sqrt \delta }\Vert \alpha(x-y) \Vert \bigr) \cdot 
\bigl( \sqrt \delta \Vert \beta(v-w) \Vert \bigr)
$$
and then apply Young's inequality with $a = \frac{1}{\sqrt \delta }\Vert \alpha(x-y)$, $b= \sqrt \delta \Vert \beta(v-w)$ and $p=q=2$.